# last modified files only moved ansible?

Tags: ansible

my requirement is moving files to remote host using ansible playbook.

my ansible script

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
     - copy: src=/home/bu/Bilal/site dest=/tmp owner=root group=root mode=777
```

when run playbook it has moved the file to remote.

when I have ran playbook again it will overwrite the whole folder again. I am looking, what are the files I have modified that files only get overwrite because my folder size is too large its taking so much time even single file change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Synchronize](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) module:

> Uses rsync to make synchronizing file paths in your playbooks quick and easy.

Example:

```
- name: Sync files
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ conf.dev_path }}/"
    dest: "{{ conf.host_path }}"
    delete: yes
    rsync_opts:
      - "--exclude=.*"
```

Comment: Note: for the synchronize module to work rsync needs to be installed on the managed machines

Comment: Thank you @SztupY for your useful comment! In fact, there are several notes in the provided link for the Synchronize module to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the manual. The newer versions says: The delete option requires `recursive=yes`. Also, the link to the new document page is [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html).